# why Api.getSize returns 0

Tags: haxe

I just meet haxe right now, so I'm doing some tests. However the first test I made didn't work. Why does Api.getSize() only returns `0` (regardless of type and its assigned value)?

```
import flash.sampler.Api;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a = 44;
        trace(Api.getSize(a)); // prints 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of your Flash Player?

In Adobe documentation said:

> Returns the size in memory of a specified object when used with the
>   Flash Player 9.0.115.0 or later debugger version. If used with a Flash
>   Player that is not the debugger version, this method returns 0.